# 2>&1 causes process to block

Tags: bash, io-redirection, process-management, gnu-parallel

I am trying to debug what I have done wrong in GNU Parallel (>=20190122).

This runs as expected:

```
(
  echo 1 | parallel-20190122 --pipe -j0 --tee dummy {} ::: {1..1000};
  echo Parallel is done here: See the pstree;
  pstree -p $$
) |
  cat
```

This blocks:

```
(
  echo 1 | parallel-20190122 --pipe -j0 --tee dummy {} ::: {1..1000};
  echo Parallel is done here: See the pstree;
  pstree -p $$
) 2>&1 |
  cat
```

How can `2>&1` have that effect?

This can be reproduced in `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh93`, but not `dash`.